# How to stabilize performance on frequently updated table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I'm trying to find-out a way how to prevent performance degradation in my PostgreSQL database.

The table is updated every minute with 100,000 - 200,000 `INSERTs`. Every 5 minutes the table is updated with the same scale of aggregated `UPDATE` and a number of `DELETEs`.  Aggregations and `DELETEs` are done in a way to keep the size of the table around 10 million records.

Apparently updates are too frequent so `AUTO VACUUM` cannot be completed. I started to run `VACUUM` after each `DELETE` series. That improved behavior a lot.

I've a suspicion that periodic reindexing would help but haven't verified it yet. Actually it's very suspicious that PostgreSQL has a dedicated command for reindexing.

I have played with different `fillfactor` for the indexes, with no visible difference.

What else should I consider to make keep performance stable? Let's say that slow but stable over time is better than sometimes fast and sometimes very slow.

UPD: vacuum analyzed after each delete + reindex every 6 hours solved the issue.

Comment: can you post your version?

Comment: Jack, no I cannot post it. anyway it's fairly table simple index and fairly simple insert/update/delete/vacuum/reindex commands.

Comment: Care to explain why? Or do you mean you do not know your version for some reason?

Comment: @BLNK: Jack asked about the specific version of Postgres server. Is it 9.1, 8.3, some other? I suppose it does matter for the `AUTO VACUUM` behaviour, so if you want better answers for your scenario, it's good to answer first the comment/questions.

Comment: What pattern your UPDATEs and DELETEs follow?

Comment: Jack, Sorry, I thought the question was about source code. The Postgresql version is 9.0.4

Comment: dezso, pattern is following: INSERT INTO TheTable(*) SELECT TimeBegin, TimeEnd, FieldK, AVG(..) FROM TheTable WHERE TimeBegin>=t0 AND TimeEnd<=t1 GROUP BY FieldK;DELETE FROM TheTable  WHERE TimeBegin>=t0 AND TimeEnd<=t1 AND NOT (TimeBegin=t0 AND TimeEnd=t1)

Answer (score 2):

Some things depend on your PostgreSQL version.  On some older versions pay attention to fsm settings to make sure it can track free space in your tables for re-use.  You might also look at scheduling a periodic cluster if you can afford the downtime.  If not, pay attention to the indexes.

Comment: it's newer than fsm versions. Clustering - will check how long it takes. Acceptable periodic downtime is 1-2 min only. 1 Aggregation, vacuum and reindexing all together take ~1 min